# when I click a button, color string will change dynamically & print on the screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two button for print their color on the screen.

```
button1 = tk.Button(frame,height = 1, width = 2,bg="Red")
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(frame,height = 1, width = 2,bg="Blue")
button2.pack()
```

So when i click `Button1`, my string (`colorchange`) will include `"Red"`.
when i print that then it will write on the screen as ==>> `Red`.

Comment: Should probably include more code, and show attempts to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Example Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()


def change_color_label(color):
    color_change.set(color)

button1 = tk.Button(win, height=1, width=2, bg="Red",
                    command=lambda c='Red': change_color_label(c))
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(win, height=1, width=2, bg="Blue",
                    command=lambda c='Blue': change_color_label(c))
button2.pack()
color_change = tk.StringVar()
mylabel = tk.Label(win, textvariable=color_change)
mylabel.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

or (with out change_color_label):

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

button1 = tk.Button(win, height=1, width=2, bg="Red",
                    command=lambda: color_change.set('Red'))
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(win, height=1, width=2, bg="Blue",
                    command=lambda: color_change.set('Blue'))
button2.pack()
color_change = tk.StringVar()
mylabel = tk.Label(win, textvariable=color_change)
mylabel.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: bg_button2_is_equal_to = button2['bg']

Comment: There's no point in passing in the color as a parameter to lambda. Might as well just hard-code it into the call to `color_change` and reduce the complexity slightly: `command=lambda: color_change.set("Red")`